# what in a local PC setting can change a HttpWebRequest ServicePoint.Address?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6

What on local PC can affect ServicePoint.Address of the HttpWebRequest?
After I create a HTTP request by providing a URI:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
```

request.ServicePoint.Address having a different value.

Comment: Please add more context, including the two values.  It's never too late to read [mcve]

Comment: Sorry Dave, I am not going to write any values here. Basically cause it is not related to the question.

Comment: It's hard to help you without more complete information.  I agree, it would be very helpful for some specifics.  I'm guessing your request is being redirected, but there's no way for us to know if you insist on keeping us in the dark.

Comment: That is that http request is been redirected. Question is what in local environment can redirect a http request? And value of the http request do not add you any light to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http request can be redirected by local Proxy settings. To disable it in Windows 10 go to the Settings->Network & Internet->Proxy->Make Use a proxy server = Off, in case if you working on intranet you would need to be sure that Use setup script is Off as well.

Comment: Yep, could have told you that yesterday.  It's right there in the documentation.  But, alas, it wasn't to be.

Comment: Sorry, I have a difficulty to follow you. 1st What do you mean by "It's right there in documentation" Which documentation you reffering to? Is it possible to have a link? And 2d, how missing url value can stop you from telling that yesterday.